# Задача на Ulearn сломана, или сломан мой код

Tags: c#, структуры-данных, data-structures

Проходил задачу на Ulearn, [ссылка на задание](https://ulearn.me/course/basicprogramming2/Praktika_Otmena__ab3d7575-9bb1-4a4f-8d07-c1a7c2646f40)
собственно в подсказке написанно "сделайте как команду в паттернах и ссылка на паттерн"
делаю как в ссылке, но начинает происходить странные вещи, совершенно не ясно, должны ли мы сохранять результат UNDO в историю отмены, если да то другие тесты не проходят, если нет то почти все тесты проходят, но все равно никак не принять. хотя на моем личном компьютере все тесты успешные, ибо все горят зеленым. прикрепляю код
собственно вопрос, код правильно решает проблему? или тесты там неправильные? судя по результатам 3000 человек справились ссылка на проект [ссылка на проект на дропфайлс](https://dropmefiles.com/CN8MZ)
[image: ошибка] и собственно хочется чтобы хоть кто-то подтвердил, что мой код работает или нет, если нет, получается у меня сломаны тесты.
[image: тесты]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace TodoApplication
{
public class ListModel<TItem>
{
    public List<TItem> Items { get; }
    public LimitedSizeStack<string> lastOperations;
    public LimitedSizeStack<Tuple<TItem, string, int>> lastInfos;
    public int Limit;
    public int limitCounter;
    public bool willGrow;

    public ListModel(int limit)
    {
        willGrow = limit == 0 ? true : false;
        limitCounter = limit;
        Items = new List<TItem>();
        lastOperations = new LimitedSizeStack<string>(limit);
        lastInfos = new LimitedSizeStack<Tuple<TItem, string, int>>(limit);
        Limit = limit;
    }

    public void AddItem(TItem item)
    {
        if(limitCounter == 0 && Limit != 0) limitCounter++;
        Items.Add(item);
        if (lastOperations.Count >= Limit) lastOperations.Pop();
        lastOperations.Push("ADD");
        if (lastInfos.Count >= Limit) lastInfos.Pop();
        lastInfos.Push(Tuple.Create(item, "ADD", lastInfos.Count));
    }

    public void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        if (limitCounter == 0 && Limit != 0) limitCounter++;
        if (lastInfos.Count >= Limit) lastInfos.Pop();
        lastInfos.Push(Tuple.Create(Items[index], "ADD", index));
        if (lastOperations.Count >= Limit) lastOperations.Pop();
        lastOperations.Push("REMOVE");
        Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public bool CanUndo()
    {
        return limitCounter > 0 && lastOperations.Count >= 1;
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        
        if (CanUndo())
        {
            limitCounter--;
            string lastOperation = lastOperations.Pop();
            Invoker invoker = new Invoker();
            Reciever<TItem> reciver = new Reciever<TItem>();
            switch (lastOperation)
            {
                case "ADD":
                    UndoAddComand<TItem> comand = new UndoAddComand<TItem>(reciver, this);
                    invoker.SetOnUndoAdd(comand);
                    break;
                case "REMOVE":
                    UndoRemoveComand<TItem> remove = new UndoRemoveComand<TItem>(reciver, this);
                    invoker.SetOnUndoRemove(remove);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            invoker.DoSomethingImportant();
            invoker.SetOnUndoAdd(null);
            invoker.SetOnUndoRemove(null);
        }
    }
}
class Reciever<T>
{
    public void UndoAdd(ListModel<T> list)
    {
        var current = list.lastInfos.Pop();
        //list.RemoveItem(list.Items.Count - 1);
        //if (list.lastOperations.Count >= list.Limit) list.lastOperations.Pop();
       // list.lastOperations.Push("REMOVE");
        //if (list.lastInfos.Count >= list.Limit) list.lastInfos.Pop();
        //list.lastInfos.Push(current);
        list.Items.RemoveAt(list.Items.Count - 1);
    }
        

    public void UndoRemove(ListModel<T> list)
    {
        var current = list.lastInfos.Pop();
        //list.AddItem(current.Item1);
        list.Items.Insert(current.Item3, current.Item1);
        //if (list.lastOperations.Count >= list.Limit) list.lastOperations.Pop();
        //list.lastOperations.Push("ADD");
        //if (list.lastInfos.Count >= list.Limit) list.lastInfos.Pop();
        //list.lastInfos.Push(current);
    }
}
class Invoker
{
    private IComand onUndoAdd;

    private IComand onUndoRemove;

    public void SetOnUndoAdd(IComand comand)
    {
        this.onUndoAdd = comand;
    }

    public void SetOnUndoRemove(IComand comand)
    {
        this.onUndoRemove = comand;
    }

    public void DoSomethingImportant()
    {
        if (this.onUndoAdd is IComand)
        {
            this.onUndoAdd.Execute();
        }


        if (this.onUndoRemove is IComand)
        {
            this.onUndoRemove.Execute();
        }
    }
}
class UndoRemoveComand<T> : IComand
{
    private Reciever<T> reciever;
    private ListModel<T> list;

    public UndoRemoveComand(Reciever<T> _reciever, ListModel<T> _list)
    {
        reciever = _reciever;
        list = _list;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        reciever.UndoRemove(list);
    }
}
class UndoAddComand<T> : IComand
{
    private Reciever<T> reciever;
    private ListModel<T> list;

    public UndoAddComand(Reciever<T> _reciever, ListModel<T> _list)
    {
        reciever = _reciever;
        list = _list;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        reciever.UndoAdd(list);
    }
}
public interface IComand
{
    void Execute();
}
}
```

заодно скажите правильно реализована команда? И непонимаю что судя по заданию не нужно или нужно сохранять UNDO в историю, я запутался

Comment: а почему у вас все поля публичные? что такое `LimitedSizeStack`?

Comment: `RemoveItem` - обратите внимание на `"ADD"` внутри, кажись опечатка. Вообще не понятно, как оно тесты прошло в таком случае. Вообще дублирование информации - штука не хорошая. А так, чтобы понять, что там за NullReferenceException, надо видеть сам тест, который падает.

Comment: LimitedSizeStack это двусвязный список реализованный на LinkedList c#

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код:

```
8. public List<TItem> Items { get; }
```

Как по мне, ошибка в том, что вы не указали возможность set полю

```
8. public List<TItem> Items { get; set;}
```

Comment: спасибо хорошее замечание, я и вправду забыл, но тем не менее сет не спас ситуацию

Comment: @Novichok2021 а зачем там set? всё правильно было. Set нужен тогда, когда вы даете доступ на изменение свойства извне. В данном случае, это разве требуется? Представьте, если напишу во внешнем коде `list.Items = null`, то при первом же вызове `AddItem`, ваш код упадет. Это нарушение инкапсуляции, баг. Так что подумайте еще раз, быть может и свойство не нужно публично. Есть же публичные методы. Выберите один способ взаимодействия с внешним миром, не смешивайте все в кучу.

Comment: @aepot я хотел сказать просто человеку за попытку помочь спасибо. Проблема не в этом, понятно, ведь иначе у меня не было бы 26 успешных тестов. Сдается, мне код работает, проблема скорее в их тестах.

Comment: @Novichok2021 `list.Items.Insert` почему вы используете свойство, а не методы? Вы уверены, что класс `Receiver` вам не ломает логику?

Comment: @aepot, простите за то, что я тут пишу это, но как на StackOverFlow писать в личные сообщения?

Comment: @Yotic никак, здесь их нет.

Comment: @aepot не скажу, что уверен на все 100% что этот подход на мой взгляд правильный, но успешные тесты, и проход дебагером ошибок не показывает

Comment: @Novichok2021 с таким подходом вы ни чему хорошему не научитесь. Код, честно, плохой, так писать не стоит. ООП инкапсуляция - вам стоит понять смысл этого. Не выучить термин, а осознать, зачем оно вообще нужно, вы пока не осознаете. Я предлагаю править ошибки, вы отказываетесь, почему - загадка. Короч, всё что не нужно снаружи, должно быть приватным. Чем меньше всего торчит наружу - тем лучше, возмите за правило. Ну и дальше можно поизучать принципы SOLID.